# java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid resource Glassfish, Java, Jpa, EclipseLink

Tags: java, maven, jpa, glassfish, eclipselink

I have been scouring the web for more hours than I would like to admit for a fix.

I am trying to set up an application which needs to have the following:

- run on glassfish 5
- use Java EE
- use EclipseLink and JPA and automatically generate the db schema from the entities.
- maven for dependencies.

Right now I have 4 child modules and a parent module. I have declared all the maven dependencies and even the dependencies between modules. But I cannot get the app to run properly.
Here is the project folder structure:

```
-mitblick
--mitblick-persistence
---src.main.resources/META-INF/persistence.xml
---pom.xml
--mitblick-business
---pom.xml
--mitblick-client
---pom.xml
--mitblick-ear
---pom.xml
--pom.xml (<- parent pom)
```

Here are the individual pom.xml files:

Parent pom.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>mitblick.ro</groupId>
    <artifactId>mitblick</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>MitBlick Parent</name>
    <description>Mitblick Parent Project</description>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.source>1.8</java.source>
        <java.target>1.8</java.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <payara.versio>5.183.0</payara.versio>
        <jackson.jaxrs.json.version>2.9.4</jackson.jaxrs.json.version>
        <jackson.jaxrs.json.glassfish.version>2.27</jackson.jaxrs.json.glassfish.version>
        <sonar.coverage.exclusions>/**/control/*,**/dto/*,**/filter/*,**/boundary/*,**/entity/*,**/dao/*,**/exceptions/*</sonar.coverage.exclusions>

    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
                <version>7.0</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>4.12</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver</groupId>
            <artifactId>shrinkwrap-resolver-impl-maven</artifactId>
            <version>LATEST</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver</groupId>
            <artifactId>shrinkwrap-resolver-impl-maven-archive</artifactId>
            <version>LATEST</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.directory.studio</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.apache.commons.io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.jaxrs.json.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.4.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <rules>
                            <dependencyConvergence/>
                        </rules>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.3.0.603</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>verify</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>sonar</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>0.7.9</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <append>true</append>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>prepare-agent</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>prepare-agent-integration</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>prepare-agent-integration</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>jacoco-site</id>
                            <phase>verify</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>report</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.6.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <ejbVersion>3.2</ejbVersion>
                        <generateClient>true</generateClient>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.6</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.10.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.19.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <parallel>methods</parallel>
                        <threadCount>10</threadCount>
                        <includes>
                            <include>*Test</include>
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                            <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
                            <version>2.19.1</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <!-- The normal build - active by default -->
        <profile>
            <id>normal-build</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>

            <modules>
                <module>mitblick-persistence</module>
                <module>mitblick-business</module>
                <module>mitblick-client</module>
                <module>mitblick-ear</module>
            </modules>

            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Persistence pom.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>mitblick.ro</groupId>
        <artifactId>mitblick</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>mitblick-persistence</artifactId>
    <name>Mitblick Persistence</name>
    <description>Persistence layer</description>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
</project>
```

Business pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <artifactId>mitblick</artifactId>
        <groupId>mitblick.ro</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>mitblick-business</artifactId>
    <name>MitBlick Business</name>
    <description>Business layer</description>
    <packaging>ejb</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mitblick</groupId>
            <artifactId>mitblick-persistence</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
            <version>2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2-beta</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Client pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <artifactId>mitblick</artifactId>
        <groupId>mitblick.ro</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>mitblick-client</artifactId>
    <name>MitBlick Client</name>
    <description>Client layer</description>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mitblick.ro</groupId>
            <artifactId>mitblick-business</artifactId>
            <type>ejb</type>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

And lastly EAR pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>mitblick</artifactId>
        <groupId>mitblick.ro</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>mitblick-ear</artifactId>
    <packaging>ear</packaging>
    <name>Mitblick EAR Project</name>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mitblick.ro</groupId>
            <artifactId>mitblick-client</artifactId>
            <type>war</type>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <version>7</version>
                    <fileNameMapping>no-version</fileNameMapping>
                    <modules>
                        <webModule>
                            <groupId>mitblick.ro</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mitblick-client</artifactId>
                            <contextRoot>mitblick</contextRoot>
                        </webModule>
                    </modules>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

In my persistence module I have this persistence.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1"
             xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="mitblick" transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/mitblick-persistence</jta-data-source>

        <properties>

            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINE" />
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.parameters" value="true"/>
            <!--<property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="both"/>-->


            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.create-source" value="metadata"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.drop-source" value="metadata"/>
            <!--<property name="javax.persistence.sql-load-script-source" value="META-INF/load.sql"/>-->
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I have logged in to the glassfish 5 console from localhost:4848 and configured a connection pool and a jdbc resource there. I suspect this is where I have done something wrong, so I will include screenshots of it just to make sure.

Connection pool:
[Connection pool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFKy2.png)
[Connection pool additional fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3Cqo.png)

[Resource pool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMw93.png)
[Resource pool details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAOL1.png)

I really have no idea how to fix this. Here is the exception log (i cannot enter more than 30k characters for the whole server log)

```
[2018-11-07T16:48:22.825+0200] [Payara 5.183] [SEVERE] [NCLS-CORE-00026] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=50 _ThreadName=admin-thread-pool::admin-listener(1)] [timeMillis: 1541602102825] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Exception during lifecycle processing
org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentException: Invalid resource : mitblick__pm
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.prepare(EarDeployer.java:182)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:978)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepare(ApplicationLifecycle.java:438)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:540)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:549)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:545)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:544)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:575)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:567)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:566)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1475)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:111)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1857)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1733)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:564)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:251)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:166)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:516)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:213)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:182)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:156)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:218)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:95)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:260)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:177)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:53)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:524)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:89)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:94)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:33)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:569)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:549)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid resource : mitblick__pm
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectorRuntime.lookupDataSourceInDAS(ConnectorRuntime.java:593)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectorRuntime.lookupPMResource(ConnectorRuntime.java:517)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.common.PersistenceHelper.lookupPMResource(PersistenceHelper.java:63)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.ProviderContainerContractInfoBase.lookupDataSource(ProviderContainerContractInfoBase.java:71)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitInfoImpl.<init>(PersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:108)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.loadPU(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:150)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.<init>(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$1.visitPUD(JPADeployer.java:225)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$PersistenceUnitDescriptorIterator.iteratePUDs(JPADeployer.java:525)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.createEMFs(JPADeployer.java:240)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.prepare(JPADeployer.java:170)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:978)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.prepareBundle(EarDeployer.java:309)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.access$200(EarDeployer.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer$1.doBundle(EarDeployer.java:155)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer$1.doBundle(EarDeployer.java:152)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.doOnBundles(EarDeployer.java:232)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.doOnAllTypedBundles(EarDeployer.java:241)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.doOnAllBundles(EarDeployer.java:270)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.prepare(EarDeployer.java:152)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.ConnectorRuntimeException: Invalid resource : mitblick__pm
    at org.glassfish.jdbcruntime.service.JdbcDataSource.validateResource(JdbcDataSource.java:82)
    at org.glassfish.jdbcruntime.service.JdbcDataSource.setResourceInfo(JdbcDataSource.java:63)
    at org.glassfish.jdbcruntime.JdbcRuntimeExtension.lookupDataSourceInDAS(JdbcRuntimeExtension.java:142)
    at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectorRuntime.lookupDataSourceInDAS(ConnectorRuntime.java:589)
    ... 58 more
]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to figure it out by breaking a manifest file, the server just dumped part of the error it was actually getting and it turns out that I had a typo in a string constant representing a jpql query. (usr instead of user)